# Apache Tika SQL3Lite parser

Tags: sqlite, parsing, jdbc, apache-tika, tika-server

Can not parse SQL files using the docker image `apache/tika:latest-full`.

I am only sending requests to the service, not writing java code.

I start the container like so:

```bash
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9998:9998 -v `pwd`/tika-config.xml:/tika-config.xml -v `pwd`/home/user/path/jars/:/tika-extras apache/tika:latest-full --config tika-config.xml
```

`/home/user/path/jars/` contains `slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar` and `sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar.`

Passing this directory to the container sets the jar files to Tika's class path. Guidance found [here](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker)

I also include these jars in my local `CLASSPATH`.

I pass in a config file with these lines to include the desired sql parser:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.sqlite3">
    </parser>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
      <parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser"/>
    </parser>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

My requests always come back with EmptyParser being used.

`curl -T sample.sqlite http://localhost:9998/tika`

returns:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head>
        
        <meta name="X-TIKA:Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser"/>
        
        <meta name="Content-Length" content="51250176"/>
        
        <meta name="Content-Type" content="application/x-sqlite3"/>
        
        <title>&#0;</title>
        
    </head>
    
    <body/>
</html>
```

When I request from the `/parsers` endpoint I don't see a SQL parser listed. This must be the root of the issue, but I am not sure what to try next.

[Tika SQLite3Parser](https://tika.apache.org/2.9.0/api/org/apache/tika/parser/sqlite3/SQLite3Parser.html)

Update 1:

Added  `tika-parser-sqlite3-package-2.9.1.jar`, `tika-parser-sqlite3-package-2.9.1-tests.jar`, and `tika-parser-sqlite3-package-2.9.1-sources.jar` to the extras folder from the maven repo. I Removed the other jars.

I did find I had to add these manually to the docker. For some reason the command when running the docker isn't doing it for me. The config file is getting passed though so I must be doing something wrong there.

I also changed the config to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.sqlite3">
                <mime>application/x-sqlite3</mime>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
            <parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser"/>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
</properties>
```

Still getting parsed by the EmtpyParser.

Update 2:

 CLASSPATH was empty in the container. I added this to it but that didnt work either.

`export CLASSPATH=:/tika-extras/tika-parser-sqlite3-package-2.9.1.jar`

Comment: Make sure to include this jar in the extras directory:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parser-sqlite3-package/2.9.1

It includes the sqlite-jdbc jar. It also
includes the Tika parser that wraps the xerial's sqlite parser. See https://lists.apache.org/thread/55188f4lwd0zvjdd5npofn8vl65vh7zz and the response.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the help! Still getting parsed by EmptyParser. See my update to the post. Is there anything you can see that I am doing wrong, or still missing to get this working?

Comment: The tika-config doesn't look right above. There should be a class name for the sqlite parser, and the default parser shouldn't be embedded within that parser.

Comment: I got it to work just now by downloading the jar I referenced above, and putting it in tika-extras (on the host), then calling: docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9998:9998 -v \`pwd\`/tika-extras:/tika-extras apache/tika:latest-full

Comment: I bashed into the container to make sure the volume mapping worked, and it did. The https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-parser-sqlite3-package/2.9.1/tika-parser-sqlite3-package-2.9.1.jar all 12MB of it was in /tika-extras.

Comment: Thanks @TimAllison. I'll  try again once I can get back to this project. Had to drop it for the time being.